# How to unit test a code which transforms some files using third party library

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, apache-fop

I am carrying out transformations on an XML file using some XSL stylesheet and generating a PDF document using Aache FOP (details [here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/embedding.html)). A reference Java code snippet is presented below:

```
public byte[] writePdf(String xml, FopFactory fopFactory, Transformer transformer) 
    StreamSource xmlStream = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
    //fop:
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MIME_PDF, out);
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(xmlStream, res);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

`Transformer` instance and `FopFactory` are injected from outside.
In a nutshell, this program uses and 'Java XML' and 'Apache FOP' APIs to write a document using some XSL and XML resources.

Any ideas on how to unit test this piece? Is it good that the test also requires access to the XML and XSL resources?

**EDIT:**

What could be done easily:

- Testing whether method `transform` has been called by providing a mocked instance of Transformer.

What are the problem elements:

- Verifying the resulting `byte[]`. Is it a proper result or just any array?
- Is the provided xml string used during the transformation?

One way of doing this could be providing the actual XML, XSLT resources from the tests, and comparing the output stream against the expected. To me, this seems brittle, as this could easily break if underlying used API's output changes even slightly. Moreover, this is insufficient as well, as it can test just a single hard-coded test scenario.

Is the used API inherently un-testable or can this be improved?

Comment: I see down/vote for closing this question. Would have been much helpful if you had asked for more information on the question, or commented appropriately.

Comment: A unit test would use mocks for FopFactory and Transformer.

Comment: @Henry Thanks. Makes sense mocking the dependencies. Still I have a challenge of verifying what this method does with the provided dependencies. Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Test the output produced for a given input. Yet testing binary output (bytes) is really brittle. So try to get a more readable model from the output.

You could reanalyze/parse the output with [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). This provides a model which you could assert on. Better only assert the relevant properties you expect and not the complete pdf structure because the latter will be probably almost as brittle as the binary code.

Besides: Even testing the binary output for some example inputs is better than not testing at all.